# How to add a Python package to Google Cloud Composer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer, google-cloud-iam

I created a Composer environment and trying to add a Python package. When I try to add, after a while, it says "Failed to install PyPI packages". [This documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#before_you_begin) says, you should add some permissions to service account of Composer.

I added these roles to [PROJECT-ID]-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com (Compute Engine default service account) but error still happening:

- Composer Administrator
- Environment and Storage Object Administrator
- Editor
- Storage Object Viewer
- Cloud Composer API Service Agent

Which roles are necessary to add Python packages?

Comment: What is the exact error message? Project Editor has the requirement permissions. This means you have either added the permissions to the wrong service account or there is a different error happening.

Comment: Could you share the axact error messages? Are you using a VPC on your composer configuration?

Comment: The documentation you mentioned states specifically:
_The following permission is required to install Python packages in the Cloud Composer environment: composer.environments.update_.
This doesn't mean the service account but the user account that makes the change in the package list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to package version. I delimited the version value of the pymssql package like *<3.0* and it didn't fail again.

Answer (score 0):

The service account to initiate the update to a Cloud Composer environment is not the same as the service account held by the environment itself. That means the identity you are initiating the update with needs to have the update permission (`composer.environments.update`), but the environment itself needs permissions provided by `roles/composer.worker`.

Note that `roles/composer.administrator` is for managing environments, while `roles/composer.worker` is a machine role for compute instances. For this reason, the Composer Administrator roles doesn't inherit all the permissions that the Composer worker role has (because it has no use for them).

TL;DR: for the environment's service account, use `roles/composer.worker` instead of the administrator role.